# R ifelse to replace values in a column

Tags: r

I have a column in my dataframe as follows:

```
Private
Private
Private
 ?
Private
```

I want to replace this " ?" with Private. I have a solution as follows:

```
# Only replacing ? with Private 
df$var <- ifelse(df$var == " ?", " Private", df$var)
```

However when I print out the `df$var` column after the ifelse statement, these values don't seem correct. This is what I got:

```
3
3
3
Private
3
```

I don't know what went wrong here.

Comment: Try `df$var <- as.character(df$var); df$var <- ifelse(df$var == " ?", " Private", df$var)`.  The variable is probably a factor.

Comment: You are right. Thank you!

Comment: If you only want to replace the " ?" it may be more efficient to use `df$var[df$var==" ?"] <- "Private"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work, using the working example:

```
var <- c("Private", "Private", "?", "Private")
df <- data.frame(var)
df$var[which(df$var == "?")] = "Private"
```

Then this will replace the values of "?" with "Private"

The reason your replacement isn't working (I think) is as if the value in `df$var` isn't `"?"` then it replaces the element of the vector with the whole `df$var` column, not just reinserting the element you want.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the ifelse alternative replacement is returning an integer that could be interpreted as a level ... try

```
df$var <- ifelse(df$var == " ?", " Private", as.character(df$var))
```

Answer (score 1):

JCollerton's solution should work well, but if you insist using if statment, you will have to do it in a for loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if(df$var[i]==" ?"){
        df$var[i]="Private"
     }
}
```