# Create dummy variable in R excluding certain cases as NA

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

```
V1 V2
A  0
B  1
C  2
D  3
E  4
F  5
G  9
```

I want to create a dummy variable in `R` where `0 = {1}`,  `1 = {2,3,4}` and `NA = {0,5,9}`

Should be simple - can anyone help?

Comment: `d2$dummy <- ifelse(d2$V2==1,0,ifelse(d2$V2 %in% c(2,3,4),1,NA))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683599/r-ifelse-to-replace-values-in-a-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert `V2` into a `factor` and adjust the `levels` according to our need.

```
df$dummy <- factor(df$V2)
levels(df$dummy) <- list(`0`=1, `1`=c(2, 3, 4), `NA` = c(0,5,9))

df
#  V1 V2 dummy
#1  A  0    NA
#2  B  1     0
#3  C  2     1
#4  D  3     1
#5  E  4     1
#6  F  5    NA
#7  G  9    NA
```

Comment: `library(SOfun); Factor(mydf$V2, list("0" = 1, "1" = 2:4))` +1 [here :-)](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun)

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 I wasn't aware about the package. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Error in levels(cwm$prevrel) <- list(`0` = 0, `1` = c(1:4)) : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL


^Got this error?

Comment: @GeorgeTarr Have you used the backquotes properly??  Every level is surrounded by them. Further, it looks your original dataframe is different from what you have shared. Please use `dput(head(cwm))` and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::recode` on a vector:

```
> V2
[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 9
```

Specify the mapping, use a default for everything else:

```
> dplyr::recode(V2,`1` = 0, `2`=1, `3`=1, `4`=1, .default=NA_real_)
[1] NA  0  1  1  1 NA NA
```