# Update one column based on the conditions of another column using R

Tags: r, dplyr

Given a small data set as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(1:8, .Label = c("2020-12", "2021-01", 
"2021-02", "2021-03", "2021-04", "2021-05", "2021-06", "2021-07"
), class = "factor"), act_direction = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("decrease", "increase", "unchanged"
), class = "factor"), pred_direction = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("decrease", "increase"), class = "factor"), 
    direction_acc = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("false", "true"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

I try to update `direction_acc` based on `act_direction` column, more specifically, if `act_direction==unchanged`, then I want to update to the content of `direction_acc` to `true`, ignoring whatever its original values are.

The expected result:

```
     date act_direction pred_direction direction_acc
1 2020-12      decrease       decrease          true
2 2021-01      decrease       increase         false
3 2021-02     unchanged       increase          true
4 2021-03      increase       increase          true
5 2021-04      increase       increase          true
6 2021-05      increase       increase          true
7 2021-06     unchanged       increase          true
8 2021-07      increase       increase          true
```

I used code below which I find no error, but it returns an outcome which is out of expectation since other values in `direction_acc` were changed to number `1` and `2`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(direction_acc = ifelse(act_direction == "unchanged", "true", direction_acc))
```

Result:

```
     date act_direction pred_direction direction_acc
1 2020-12      decrease       decrease             2
2 2021-01      decrease       increase             1
3 2021-02     unchanged       increase          true
4 2021-03      increase       increase             2
5 2021-04      increase       increase             2
6 2021-05      increase       increase             2
7 2021-06     unchanged       increase          true
8 2021-07      increase       increase             2
```

So my question is where is error in my code and how could we achieve that correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32683599/5325862

Comment: I understand, I need to add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` option while reading data. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `direction_acc` to character:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(direction_acc = ifelse(act_direction == "unchanged", 
                                "true", 
                                as.character(direction_acc)))
     date act_direction pred_direction direction_acc
1 2020-12      decrease       decrease          true
2 2021-01      decrease       increase         false
3 2021-02     unchanged       increase          true
4 2021-03      increase       increase          true
5 2021-04      increase       increase          true
6 2021-05      increase       increase          true
7 2021-06     unchanged       increase          true
8 2021-07      increase       increase          true
```

Answer (score 1):

All columns are `factor` columns, so the printed values are the factor levels.
Instead you can convert to factor column to a character first:

```
dplyr::mutate(df, direction_acc = ifelse(act_direction == "unchanged", "true", as.character(direction_acc)))

#>      date act_direction pred_direction direction_acc
#> 1 2020-12      decrease       decrease          true
#> 2 2021-01      decrease       increase         false
#> 3 2021-02     unchanged       increase          true
#> 4 2021-03      increase       increase          true
#> 5 2021-04      increase       increase          true
#> 6 2021-05      increase       increase          true
#> 7 2021-06     unchanged       increase          true
#> 8 2021-07      increase       increase          true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `which()` to get desired result.

```
df[which(df$act_direction == "unchanged"),]$direction_acc <- "true"
```